# Add AVG, SUM to an element field

Tags: plugin-development

I want to use AVG/SUM mysql and add it to the results of a criteria.
Trying to strategize the best way to achieve this.

I'm looking at `elements.onBuildElementsQuery`, where it seems I could do something like...`$query->addSelect('AVG(field_reviewRating) as reviewRatingAverage');`

Or do I need to make this a field type (read only)?

I'm going to be dealing with several thousands of entries, so I don't want to have to query everything and loop through.

I could also just call a service from Twig e.g. (`craft.custom.getReviewStats(entryModel)`), but I wanted to avoid having to add another query for each returned element.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, since I happen to be dealing with reviews, The Star Reviews plugin calculates averages when new ratings are posted: https://www.doublesecretagency.com/plugins/star-ratings